# Excel columns from multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

So Ive been trying to copy multiple data from multiple sheets to a single sheets,  how to select all columns from multiple sheets, and place them in  some other  sheet?

Answer (score 0):

*Below written VBA code help you to Copy data from all Worksheets of active Workbook at once into a new Worksheet. But remember this code will work properly when all of the Worksheets must have the same Data structure, mean same number of Columns and Rows in the same.*

```
    Sub CommandButton1_click()

    Dim J As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

    Sheets(1).Select

    Worksheets.Add

    Sheets(1).Name = "Combined Sheet"
    Sheets(2).Activate

    Range("A1").EntireRow.Select

    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")

   For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
     Sheets(J).Activate
    Range("A1").Select

   Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
     Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
      Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A2000").End(xlUp)(2)
   Next

   End Sub
```

**NB:** In the above VBA code I've picked from Cell A1, it means in every Sheet data range starts from A1. But you can REPLACE the start Cell(A1) with other Cell, as your need.

*Hope this help you.*